# Why is the foreign key set to null when using the action 'after_create' in the model of a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, after-create

The following block of code is how my model looks.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :parent_model

  after_create :create_model
  
  after_update :update_model

  def create_model
    # some code goes here
    puts "Parent id: " + self.parent_model_id.to_s
    # parent_model_id is nil here
  end
  
  def update_model
    puts "Parent id: " + self.parent_model_id.to_s
    # parent_model_id is as it should be
  end
  
end
```

I want to access the value of its foreign key at the end of `after_create`, but it is `nil`. It throws an exception even though the other fields are not `nil` i.e., the fields of the model itself. However, the foreign key is nil.

If I try to access the foreign key using `after_update`, it works.

Why is the foreign key set to null when using the action `after_create` in the model?

Comment: First thing you gotta change the method names

Comment: @DeepakMahakale Thank you, I did it but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails wraps its changes to a database inside a transaction, and `after_create` and `after_update` callbacks run inside that transaction. This means that when you call an `after_create` method the changes to the database are not implemented, which will result in a `null` value for the 'parent_model_id'.

An `after_update` callback occurs when a record is created and updated. In that case, the 'parent_model_id' will be always available and an error is not thrown.

You can use another callback named `after_commit`. It is called when all changes to a database are completed, and it occurs in both cases; thus, creating a new record and updating an existing one.

Comment: you can check self values by adding `binding.pry` in both methods and check the difference

Comment: Thank you, I understand it. Is there any way to make a distinguish inside `after_commit` between `after_create` and `after_update` ?

Comment: you can use `:on` option with callback e.g `after_commit :create_model, on: [:create]` or use aliase `after_create_commit`

Comment: check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#transaction-callbacks for more details